# Finding inflection points along arbitrary axis

Tags: geometry, line

I'm trying to find the inflection points relative to given axis (green line) given a series of (blue) points that form a path. We can see from the diagram below there are two inflection points (pink lines), or places where the path changes direction relative to the task axis.

[image]

The tricky part is that the direction of the axis may change, so it has to work going in any direction. My first attempt takes 2 consecutive points along the path, gets the direction between them, and then compares it to the direction of the axis.

Skipping a few boring steps (like recording previous points), the pseudocode looks like this:

```
foreach point cur_point in path:
    direction = prev_point - cur_point
    (normalize direction)
    relative_direction = dir_towards_axis - direction
    (normalize relative direction)
    if the sign of either x or y has changed between relative_direction and prev_relative_direction
        # we have found an inflection point
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Any pointers on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find needed points, you can detect sign change of [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) between axis and current curve direction (orientation/handedness test).

```
 axis_direction = axis_end - axis_start = B - A
 ....
 direction = cur_point - prev_point
 cross =  cross_product(direction, axis_direction) = 
          direction.x * axis_direction.y - direction.y * axis_direction.x
```

*Note: If your curve is continuous and analytic, closed-form formula might exist*

Comment: I implemented this approach, and it worked. Thanks! When using many points to create a path (120 points/sec sampling of the mouse position), this method is extremely sensitive to minute direction changes. I suppose I could sample fewer points, likely washing out small direction changes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#aligning - the idea is to align your baseline with the x or y axis, by moving every point by `{-p1.x, -p1.y}` and then rotating all the coordinates that define your curve (*provided your curve is invariant to affine transforms!*) so that your last coordinate lies on the axis (for which you use the `atan2` function to find the angle to rotate by, which virtually all programming languages come with).

Once axis-aligned, you can perform whatever analysis "with respect to the axis" you need done.